# Problem with URI matcher in Android

Tags: android, uri, provider

I have an authority string defined as such:

```
public final static String AUTHORITY = "dsndata.sds2mobile.jobprovider";
```

Followed by an edition to the UriMatcher:

```
uriMatcher.addURI(JobMetaData.AUTHORITY, "/JobNames/*",
                      JOBNAME_SINGLE_URI);
```

The uri that gets passed to the switch is:

```
content://dsndata.sds2mobile.jobprovider/JobNames/test
```

This falls through the switch and hits the default (which throws an IllegalArgumentException).

Am I missing something? I've searched and can't find anything that would account for the mismatch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem too with IllegalArgumentException. Even those have debugging the Uri's were the same! [drove me crazy]. If you have defined */ match first that seems to match and prevent others from matching. **ORDER IS IMPORTANT!!**

I reordered and the 'external_warning_id' now works fine.

```
//putting it first as /* seems to get matched first
    URL_MATCHER.addURI(AUTHORITY, TABLE_NAME.toLowerCase() + "/external_warning_id" + "/*",
            EXTERNAL_WARNING_ID);

// was the first entry in static block
URL_MATCHER.addURI(AUTHORITY, TABLE_NAME.toLowerCase() + "/*", WARNING__ID);
```

Answer (score 4):

Try removing the leading slash:

```
uriMatcher.addURI(JobMetaData.AUTHORITY, "JobNames/*",
                  JOBNAME_SINGLE_URI);
```

instead of

```
uriMatcher.addURI(JobMetaData.AUTHORITY, "/JobNames/*",
                  JOBNAME_SINGLE_URI);
```

---

### (Update)

With the code supplied, **I got it working by moving that line to the top**. The order of definition is important and it seems some of your other matchers somehow conflict. Anyway, moving it to the top worked.

Comment: Nope. It still falls through to the default.

Comment: This is how I have defined it and all the samples I have seen. Have you recompiled and redeployed? I am pretty sure that is the problem.

Comment: I did a Clean and rebuilt. Still not matching. Is there any other relevant code I should post?

Comment: Are you implementing custom provider? If not please post the code you are using. If yes, then take out the code and put under your main activity's `onCreate` and run to make sure it does the same. LogCat is also useful + all your matches you have defined.

Comment: I am implementing a custom provider. http://pastebin.com/WhK9QVtZ There is the code for the provider and here is the code for the meta data http://pastebin.com/p1f1kvEE.  (The spacing got a little screwy after the paste)

Comment: See my update. Move it up (first match condition definition) and it worked.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! Any idea what my conflict could be? I've been looking at this code for a while now. The fresh eyes help.

Comment: I could not find out. I removed the dodgy */*/* but made no difference so it could be others. To be honest, uriMatching in android is a bit flaky and half-baked.